# Is the Grails RestBuilder thread-safe?

Tags: grails

Is the 'grails.plugins.rest.client.RestBuilder' thread-safe?

Can it be injected into a grails service via resources.groovy?

Thanks

Mark

Comment: The answer to the second question is "yes".  That is true even for things that are not thread safe.  If you are injecting non-thread safe beans into other beans, those other beans should be configured as request scoped, or possibly prototype scoped, depending on how they are being used.  You just need to make sure that no 2 threads are concurrently interacting with any non-thread safe bean.

Comment: How do you specify the proxy scope of a bean in resources.groovy?

scopedProxy does not work

    testBean(TestBean){
        it.scope = 'request'
        it.scopedProxy = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS
    }

Comment: `it.scope = 'request'` should work.  Depending on how you are retrieving the bean, it might look like it doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

```
restBuilderContainer(RestBuilder) {
    it.scope = 'request'
}

restBuilder(ScopedProxyFactoryBean) {
    targetBeanName = 'restBuilderContainer'
    proxyTargetClass = true
}
```

ScopedProxyFactoryBean did the trick.